# iOS: analysing audio while recording video to apply image filters

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, video, recording

I'm desperate to find a solution to the following problem: I have an iPhone application that:

1. can record Video and audio from the camera and microphone to a video file
2. perform some audio processing algorithms in real-time (while the video is being recorded)
3. Apply filters to the video (while it's recording) that are modified by the latter algorithms

I've accomplished all of the tasks separately using some libraries ([GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) for the filters, and AVFoundation for basic audio processing) but I haven't been able to combine the audio analysis and the video recording simultaneously, i.e: it records perfectly the video file and applies the filters correctly, but the audio processing part just STOPS when I start to record the video.

I've tried with AVAudioSession, AVAudioRecorder and have looked all around google and this page but I couldn't find anything. I suspect that it has to do with concurrent access to the audio data (the video recording process stops the audio processing because of concurrency) but either way I don't know how to fix it

Any ideas? anyone? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using GPUImage for recording the video as well? I'd assume so, for best performance. If you do this, the GPUImageVideoCamera class sets up its own access to the microphone and any additional access will cause a conflict as two different things try to hit that one device. What you're going to need is some way to intercept the audio packets between GPUImageVideoCamera and GPUImageMovieWriter for your processing. I don't currently have a mechanism for this, but you might be able to modify the class similar to how video sample buffers can now be extracted for facial detection.